# why won't this code compile in AOT mode?

Tags: javascript, angular

I have a piece of code below, why would it not compile in `AOT` mode?

```
@Component({
  selector: 'talk-cmp',
  template: () => window.hide ? 'hidden' : `
    {{talk.title}} {{talk.speaker}}
    Rating: {{ talk.rating | formatRating }}
    <watch-button [talk]="talk"></watch-button>
    <rate-button [talk]="talk" (click)="onRate()"></rate-button>
  `
})
class TalkCmp {
  //...
}
```

The culprit here is `window.hide`, what i am not understanding is how come `talk.title` or `talk.speaker` gets compiled? Are they not dynamic code?

Is it like anything which is not defined in my application will fail during Aot mode?

Comment: And what does 'not compile' exactly mean?

Comment: I was going through this article, was not clear... so asked here... https://blog.nrwl.io/essential-angular-2-compilation-cfbebf9bb6e4#.59e8c1s9k

Comment: It makes more sense with this reference, I would suggest to add it to the question for context. Sure, they are dynamic, they will likely be replaced with getter functions. You can check the code that was generated with AoT for details. The point here is that `talk...` are bindings inside the template, and `window.hide` is not.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

AOT requires that all your templates be statically analyzable. In other words, you can understand exactly what other components/directives/pipes/bindings the template is using simply by looking at the code **without** running it.  In the example given, you don't know what the template would be because the actual template string for the component depends on a value *(window.hide)* that is only known when you run the code.

Comment: Thanks, so you mean to say if i have some function named XYZ defined in my component itself in place of window.hide, will it be the same?

Comment: If you use XYZ in a template binding within the template, that's fine. But the template string itself has to be a constant